# Cypress: How to return a boolean from custom commands?

Tags: typescript, cypress, e2e-testing

I am trying to write a custom command that will take element selector as argument and return a boolean indicating if the element is present or not. But the custom command is stating the following:

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'CanReturnChainable'
```

Here is the code for my custom command.

```
declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable<Subject> {
            isPresent(elementSelector: string): boolean;
        }
    }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('isPresent', (elementSelector) => {
    console.log(document.querySelector(elementSelector))
    debugger;
    return !!document.querySelector(elementSelector);
})

export {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the result,

```
Cypress.Commands.add('isPresent', (elementSelector) => {
  const isPresent = !!document.querySelector(elementSelector);
  return cy.wrap(isPresent);                        // this gives you a Chainable
})
```

but then you need to unwrap inside the test

```
it('', () => {

  cy.isPresent('#my-element').then(isPresent => {      // unwrap 
    if (isPresent) {
      ...
```

I'm not sure about the type definition, perhaps it should return `Chainable<Boolean>`.